# What's the functionaliy of the clusterIp created by ingress controller?

Tags: kubernetes, reverse-proxy, kubernetes-ingress

after deploying nginx ingress controller there are two services in the nginx namespace

```
NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP      
ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.28.13.78    
ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.28.8.39
```

I understand the external ip maps to the external load balancer that routes traffic to ingress,  but what is the functionality of this ClusterIP ?
Does this clusterIP routes traffic to application services, and then application pods?

Comment: Every Service gets a cluster-internal IP address allocated to it, even if the Service is primarily intended to be called from outside the cluster.

Answer (score 2):

> I understand the external ip maps to the external load balancer that
> routes traffic to ingress, but what is the functionality of this
> ClusterIP ?

`ClusterIP` type service abstraction is also doing a load balancing but cluster internal. It's not some running instance as a load balancer you already know. `kube-proxy` configures `ip-tables` rules for each pod fronted by this `ClusterIP` service and randomly routes traffic to different pods (as the same TCP session packets will directed to the same pod otherwise pods will end up not being able to decode meaningful data).

> Does this clusterIP routes traffic to application
> services, and then application pods?

No, That's not right. To send traffic from Ingress to application pods it uses a `ClusterIP` of the application service. Here you also get a `ClusterIP` when creating a `LoadBalancer` type service by default. It is for convenience to not use external IP for internal service to Ingress communication that you may want.

For example: If you want to call a service fronted by ingress but from a pod in the same cluster, then you can use `ClusterIP` and avoid *traffic hair-pinning* (traffic initiated from the cluster leaving the cluster and re-entering the cluster again).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I feel like you explained what a clusterIP does, but didn't specifically answer my question, which is what is this clusterIP from Ingress installation for ?

Comment: @user2600411, in the second quoted section I have provided an answer for that! You get one ClusterIP for each service by default even though you set the type as LoadBalancer or NodePort. It is for convenience to access those services efficiently when used internally. Traffic no need to go to the external load balancer and come back

Answer (score -1):

It relates to the admission webhook. Here is [reference](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/how-it-works/) to the documentation:

> Avoiding outage from wrong configuration
>
> Because the ingress controller works using the synchronization loop
> pattern, it is applying the configuration for all matching objects. In
> case some Ingress objects have a broken configuration, for example a
> syntax error in the nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet
> annotation, the generated configuration becomes invalid, does not
> reload and hence no more ingresses will be taken into account.
>
> To prevent this situation to happen, the Ingress-Nginx Controller
> optionally exposes a validating admission webhook server to ensure the
> validity of incoming ingress objects. This webhook appends the
> incoming ingress objects to the list of ingresses, generates the
> configuration and calls nginx to ensure the configuration has no
> syntax errors.